# How to build a specific app (Messaging) from Android Open Source Project (AOSP)?

Tags: android, git, build, messaging, android-source

I have downloaded the source code of [Messaging](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Messaging/) using git as below.

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Messaging
```

I have the checked official [Android Document](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) for download & build from android source code. But I can't find how to build for the specific app like Messaging or some other.

I want to build the `Messaging` app from tag `android-7.1.1_r13`.

How do I build the `Messaging` app from Android Open Source Project (AOSP) ?

Answer (score 0):

Surely, this project (messaging app) has framework dependencies, for example ContactsCommon.
If you have the AOSP code, put yourself in the root of the code and:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch //select the correct device
mma Messaging
```

I hope this works for you